# C++ vectorization of conditional code with intrinsics

Tags: c++, vectorization, conditional-statements, intrinsics

I tried to enable vectorization of an often-used function to improve the performance.

The algorithm should do the following and is called ~4.000.000 times!

```
Input:  double* cellvalue 
Output: int8*   Output (8 bit integer, c++ char)
```

Algo:

```
if (cellvalue > upper_threshold )
    *output = 1;
else if (cellvalue < lower_threshold)
    *output = -1;
else
    *output = 0;
```

My first vectorization approach to compute 2 doubles in parallel looks like:

```
__m128d lowerThresh = _mm_set1_pd(m_lowerThreshold);
__m128d upperThresh = _mm_set1_pd(m_upperThreshold);

__m128d vec = _mm_load_pd(cellvalue);
__m128d maskLower = _mm_cmplt_pd(vec, lowerThresh); // less than
__m128d maskUpper = _mm_cmpgt_pd(vec, upperThresh); // greater than

static const tInt8 negOne = -1;
static const tInt8 posOne =  1;
output[0] = (negOne & *((tInt8*)&maskLower.m128d_f64[0])) | (posOne & *((tInt8*)&maskUpper.m128d_f64[0]));
output[1] = (negOne & *((tInt8*)&maskLower.m128d_f64[1])) | (posOne & *((tInt8*)&maskUpper.m128d_f64[1]));
```

Does this make sense to you? It works, but I think the last part to create the output is very complicated. Is there any faster method to do this?

Also I tried to compute 8 values at once with nearly the same code. Will this perform better? Does the order of instructions make sense?

```
__m128d lowerThresh = _mm_set1_pd(m_lowerThreshold);
__m128d upperThresh = _mm_set1_pd(m_upperThreshold);

// load 4 times
__m128d vec0 = _mm_load_pd(cellValue);
__m128d vec1 = _mm_load_pd(cellValue + 2);
__m128d vec2 = _mm_load_pd(cellValue + 4);
__m128d vec3 = _mm_load_pd(cellValue + 6);
__m128d maskLower0 = _mm_cmplt_pd(vec0, lowerThresh); // less than
__m128d maskLower1 = _mm_cmplt_pd(vec1, lowerThresh); // less than
__m128d maskLower2 = _mm_cmplt_pd(vec2, lowerThresh); // less than
__m128d maskLower3 = _mm_cmplt_pd(vec3, lowerThresh); // less than
__m128d maskUpper0 = _mm_cmpgt_pd(vec0, upperThresh); // greater than
__m128d maskUpper1 = _mm_cmpgt_pd(vec1, upperThresh); // greater than
__m128d maskUpper2 = _mm_cmpgt_pd(vec2, upperThresh); // greater than
__m128d maskUpper3 = _mm_cmpgt_pd(vec3, upperThresh); // greater than

static const tInt8 negOne = -1;
static const tInt8 posOne =  1;
output[0] = (negOne & *((tInt8*)&maskLower0.m128d_f64[0])) | (posOne & *((tInt8*)&maskUpper0.m128d_f64[0]));
output[1] = (negOne & *((tInt8*)&maskLower0.m128d_f64[1])) | (posOne & *((tInt8*)&maskUpper0.m128d_f64[1]));
output[2] = (negOne & *((tInt8*)&maskLower1.m128d_f64[0])) | (posOne & *((tInt8*)&maskUpper1.m128d_f64[0]));
output[3] = (negOne & *((tInt8*)&maskLower1.m128d_f64[1])) | (posOne & *((tInt8*)&maskUpper1.m128d_f64[1]));
output[4] = (negOne & *((tInt8*)&maskLower2.m128d_f64[0])) | (posOne & *((tInt8*)&maskUpper2.m128d_f64[0]));
output[5] = (negOne & *((tInt8*)&maskLower2.m128d_f64[1])) | (posOne & *((tInt8*)&maskUpper2.m128d_f64[1]));
output[6] = (negOne & *((tInt8*)&maskLower3.m128d_f64[0])) | (posOne & *((tInt8*)&maskUpper3.m128d_f64[0]));
output[7] = (negOne & *((tInt8*)&maskLower3.m128d_f64[1])) | (posOne & *((tInt8*)&maskUpper3.m128d_f64[1]));
```

Hopefully you can help me to understand the vectorization thing a bit better ;)

Comment: If we are going for optimizations, then using the native integer size of your CPU, rather than 8-bit int, could be faster.

Comment: I'll do a bit count on the mask and do *output = (int8_t)(numGT- numLT), if your compare intrinsics returns 0/1 as false/true.

Comment: if possible you should use AVX/2 where you can work with 4 doubles at a time, or write 2 separate versions for SSE and AVX in case you need to support legacy targets

Answer (score 3):

`_mm_cmplt_pd` and `_mm_cmpgt_pd` produce a result that is already either `0` or `-1`; `and`ing it with `-1` does nothing, and `and`ing it with `1` is equivalent to negating it.  Thus, if `upper_threshold > lower_threshold` (so that both conditions are never true), you can just write*:

```
_mm_storeu_si128(output, _mm_sub_epi64(maskLower, maskUpper));
```

(*) it's unclear what an "int8" is in your code; that's not a standard type in C++.  It could be an 8-byte int, which is the behavior I've used here.  If it's an 8-bit int instead, you'll want to pack up a bunch of results to store together.

---

Questioner clarifies that they intend `int8` to be an 8-bit integer.  In that case, you can do the following for a quick implementation:

```
__m128i result = _mm_sub_epi64(maskLower, maskUpper)
output[0] = result.m128i_i64[0]; // .m128i_i64 is an oddball MSVC-ism, so
output[1] = result.m128i_i64[1]; // I'm not 100% sure about the syntax here.
```

but you may also want to try packing eight result vectors together and store them with a single store operation.

Comment: Given that the output is in {-1,0,1} I think it is fair to assume his `int8` is probably an 8-bit int.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try that tomorrow. The Output should as small as possible and int8 means 8 bit (char) in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the code not to branch, then a modern compiler will do the vectorization for you.

Here's the test I ran:

```
#include <stdint.h>                                                                             
#include <iostream>                                                                             
#include <random>                                                                               
#include <vector>                                                                               
#include <chrono>                                                                               

using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;                                                        
using std::chrono::milliseconds;                                                                

typedef double Scalar;                                                                          
typedef int8_t Integer;                                                                         

const Scalar kUpperThreshold = .5;                                                              
const Scalar kLowerThreshold = .2;                                                              

void compute_comparisons1(int n, const Scalar* xs, Integer* ys) {                               
#pragma simd                                                                                    
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {                                                                     
    Scalar x   = xs[i];                                                                         
    ys[i] = (x > kUpperThreshold) - (x < kLowerThreshold);                                      
  }                                                                                             
}                                                                                               

void compute_comparisons2(int n, const Scalar* xs, Integer* ys) {                               
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {                                                                     
    Scalar x   = xs[i];                                                                         
    Integer& y = ys[i];                                                                         
    if (x > kUpperThreshold)                                                                    
      y = 1;                                                                                    
    else if(x < kLowerThreshold)                                                                
      y = -1;                                                                                   
    else                                                                                        
      y = 0;                                                                                    
  }                                                                                             
}                                                                                               

const int N = 4000000;                                                                          

auto random_generator = std::mt19937{0};                                                        

int main() {                                                                                    
  std::vector<Scalar> xs(N);                                                                    
  std::vector<Integer> ys1(N);                                                                  
  std::vector<Integer> ys2(N);                                                                  

  std::uniform_real_distribution<Scalar> dist(0, 1);                                            
  for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)                                                                       
    xs[i] = dist(random_generator);                                                             


  auto time0 = Clock::now();                                                                    
  compute_comparisons1(N, xs.data(), ys1.data());                                               
  auto time1 = Clock::now();                                                                    
  compute_comparisons2(N, xs.data(), ys2.data());                                               
  auto time2 = Clock::now();                                                                    

  std::cout << "v1: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<milliseconds>(time1 - time0).count() << "\n";
  std::cout << "v2: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<milliseconds>(time2 - time1).count() << "\n";

  for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) {                                                                     
    if (ys1[i] != ys2[i]) {                                                                     
      std::cout << "Error!\n";                                                                  
      return -1;                                                                                
    }                                                                                           
  }                                                                                             
  return 0;                                                                                     
}
```

If you compile with a recent version of gcc (I used 4.8.3) and use the flags "-O3 -std=c++11 -march=native -S", you can verify by looking at the assembly that it vectorizes the code. And it runs much faster (3 milliseconds vs 16 milliseconds on my machine.)

Also, I'm not sure what your requirements are; but if you can live with less precision, then using float instead of double will further improve the speed (double takes 1.8x as long on my machine)

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try, but i had to compile with VS2010, so there is no auto vectorization available :(